# Regex - split by dot if it is at the end of word

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

The next regular expression splits by space and comma.

```
New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[ ,]+")
```

In addition, I want it to split by dot **only if the dot is found in the end of a word**.

For example:

```
"text." - Split.
"2.2"   - Don't Split.
"2.a"   - Don't Split.
```

This is my regex:

```
New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[ ,]+")
```

(If I add dot after the comma, it splits the dots without considering their locations in the string)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ^    The beginning of a line
- $    The end of a line
- \b   A word boundary
- \B   A non-word boundary
- \A   The beginning of the input
- \G   The end of the previous match
- \Z   The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
- \z   The end of the input

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Try it

```
New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[ ,]+$")
```

Comment: This will split if any of the characters are anchored to the end of the string. The OP needs an OR condition.

Comment: The original post has a C# tag, and you reference Java-related regex flavor Web site.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ ,]+|\.$
```

or

```
[ ,]+|\\.$
```

Try this.See demo.Use `Multiline` mode.

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/6

Answer (score 0):

You can add a word boundary test right after the dot. Try this one:

`[ ,]+|\.\b`

In your case, use it the following way:

`New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[ ,]+|\\.\\b")`

or (preferred)

`New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[ ,]+|\.\b")`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the $ to state the end of line

```
   New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[ ,]+.$")
```